# zf2 resolve module view path

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

Starting from the skeleton application using beta3 how would you resolve the view path for a new module called Foo?

I have added below to the di config and now both modules action's render Foo's views.

```
'Zend\View\Resolver\TemplatePathStack' => array(
    'parameters' => array(
        'paths'  => array(
            'foo' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
),
```

I would expect `Application\Controller\IndexController::indexAction()` to render the views in Application and for `Foo\Controller\IndexController::indexAction()` to render Foo's views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that questions like this help shape the direction of the stable framework. :)

One idea I've been toying with is to use the module as part of the view script resolution. Right now, the default used is "/"; my proposal is to use "//", as this would help prevent naming conflicts between modules; it also makes it much simpler to understand exactly what view script you are overriding if you use template maps.

You can use this approach today, but it will require manually setting the template on the view models you return from your controllers.

Comment: Not sure I follow, what do you mean by using a double forward slash?

Comment: SO ate my content. I meant to say "Right now, the default used is '{controller}/{action}'; my proposal is to use '{module}/{controller}/{action}'". This is in fact what we did for the stable framework.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't currently work in ZF2 as there is no concept of taking the namespace into account  when resolving view scripts. Discussions are currently ongoing on how best to tackle this.

For the time being, you have to name each controller differently. In general, we are recommending that you name the "primary" controller within a module after the module name. That is, the primary controller in the `Foo` module would be `FooController`.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can do this; and it is not too bad....

Rob Allen himself had a blog post that basically makes this work...  Notice you have to basically handle it as a module based loader that separates much of the work out so that we don't have controllers utilizing it:  http://pastie.org/3824571